# Convention for referencing class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, conventions, class-variables

What is the convention for referencing class attributes? I understand that there are two ways of referencing class attributes:

```
class Circle1:
    pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self, radius=1):
        self.radius = radius

    def get_circumference():
        return 2 * self.pi * self.radius

class Circle2:
    pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self, radius=2):
        self.radius = radius

    def get_circumference():
        return 2 * Circle2.pi * self.radius
```

The first way is referencing it as `self.attribute`, while the second way is to reference it as `Class.attribute`. Which way is the convention for referencing class attributes? Or is there no convention and is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: I am not aware of a convention, but I can think of one reason why you might prefer to use the class name: it communicates to the reader that `pi` is a class attribute. On the other hand, you might want to change the name of `Circle2` to `Sphere`, at which point you would have to edit all functions that use class attributes (which is easy with all but the most primitive text editors). I would advise that you use whichever convention communicates your intention most clearly to the reader (your future self, or someone else).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you're going to use it. `Class.attribute` will set it as an attribut for **all** instances of that class, while `self.attribute` is only for specific instances. In your case, `pi` is *always* (around) 3.14, so it should be a class attribute, while the radius is specific to any one circle, so it should be set as `self.radius`.

---

Also, to help shorten your code, you should only use 1 class of circles, and make the radius mandatory (don't specify default) because that is the only thing that changes.

Comment: I understand the difference between class attributes and instance attributes, but I was asking what the convention is to reference the class attributes. You can reference a class attribute (in my case `pi`) by either using `self.pi` or `Circle.pi`. I was asking which of those two is the convention, if there is any.

Comment: Oh OK, so from reading the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), I saw that it would be referring to the instance, not the class (so `self.pi`).